# Groups in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements in a group $G$. Prove that 
$$ab^na^{-1} = (aba^{-1})^n$$
for any $n \in Z$.

Hint: Try it for $n = 2$, and then generalize to all positive $n$. Then show it works for negative $n$. You may take as fact that for any $g \in G$, 
$$\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdots g \cdot g}_{n\ \text{times}} = g^n,$$
and similarly for negative exponents.

Comment: Please fix this up or ask someone else to-it's really hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Try using induction. That is what they are hinting you should do.

Comment: What is your definition for $g^{-n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1):

Take $n = 3$ for example,

$$(aba^{-1})(aba^{-1})(aba^{-1}) = ab(a^{-1}a)b(a^{-1}a)ba^{-1} = abbba^{-1} = ab^3a^{-1}$$

This should give you an idea of how it works in general.

The inductive step looks like this:

$$(aba^{-1})^{n+1} = (aba^{-1})^n(aba^{-1}) = ab^na^{-1}aba^{-1} = a b^n b a^{-1} = a b^{n+1} a^{-1}$$

Use $a^{-n} = (a^{-1})^n$ to extend this to negative exponents.

Answer (score 0):

$$(aba^{-1})^n = \underbrace{aba^{-1}\cdot aba^{-1}\cdots aba^{-1}}_{n \,times} = a \underbrace{b\cdots b}_{n\, times}a^{-1} = ab^na^{-1}$$

By using $a^{-n} = (a^{-1})^n$ this can also be generalized to negative exponents. However,
If you want this to be more formal then you have to induct on n.